# Using PostGIS with Postgres.app (9.3)

Tags: postgis, postgresql

I'm trying to run CREATE EXTENSION postgis; on a fresh 9.3 Postgres.app install.

I get this as a return:

```
ERROR:  cannot change return type of existing function
HINT:  Use DROP FUNCTION st_approxsummarystats(text,text,integer,boolean,double precision) first.
********** Error **********

ERROR: cannot change return type of existing function
SQL state: 42P13
Hint: Use DROP FUNCTION st_approxsummarystats(text,text,integer,boolean,double precision) first.
```

So I tried to drop the function in question and run it again. It still can't get past this point. I am used to developing on Linux with a reqular Postgres install, so using Postgres.app is new to me.

Comment: Is this on an empty database, or a restored backup? And what OS X system version are you running?

Comment: It's a backup. I tried again with an empty db and it worked. I'll just recreate the tables from scratch. For future reference, is there a way to restore AND be able to use PostGIS?

Comment: I just upgraded from 9.2 to 9.3 and restored a database without this problem (but the restore brought in the extensions, too, didn't try to CREATE EXTENSION afresh).